# Al-Fatemi (Lisaan-ud-Dawat) font not support in Chrome browser

Tags: css, fonts, arabic, arabic-support

The DAWOODI BOHRA Community’s official language is LISAAN UD DAWAT, and technical people within our community have developed FONTS like “Al-Fatemi(Lisaan-Ud-Dawat)” etc. for our Language, We use these fonts in most of our websites.

LISAAN UD DAWAT is slightly different from ARABIC, we have some extra characters in it which is used by double key stroke, for eg.

- There is No such character as “P” in Arabic, but we have in LISAAN UD DAWAT,
- We make the word “P” by pressing “E” twice in “Al-Fatemi(Lisaan-Ud-Dawat)” fonts.
- There is No such character as “CH” in Arabic, but we have in LISAAN UD DAWAT,
- We make the word “CH” by pressing “P” twice in “Al-Fatemi(Lisaan-Ud-Dawat)” fonts.
- There is No such character as “G” in Arabic, but we have in LISAAN UD DAWAT,
- We make the word “G” by pressing “;” twice in “Al-Fatemi(Lisaan-Ud-Dawat)” fonts.

Since last some time we are noticing that the “Double Key Stroke” support has been withdrawn from all major browser. And we are not able to use our FATEMI Fonts online.

I request you to enable support for these fonts or suggest us any solution for the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a product feature request, which would belong on a browser vendor's communication channel.

Comment: Yakin, can you reword this to ask the question as to how to fix the problem? If you can link to your publicly available font files, and show some screenshots of the problem, then maybe someone can suggest a solution. Presently it looks like you have posted this in the wrong forum, _and_ the problem is not too clear.